# url rewrite using htaccess without redirection

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like this:
http://www.localhost.com/code_category/computers/

I want to change this url to:
http://www.localhost.com/category/computers/

**I don't need url redirection.**
My current htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this wordpress or some other CMS?

Answer (score 1):

**.htaccess** file

Add this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost.com [NC,OR]

# without redirect
# RewriteRule ^/code_category/computers/$ category/computers/
RewriteRule ^/category/computers/$ code_category/computers/

# redirect method
# RedirectMatch 301 ^/code_category/computers/$ category/computers/
```

- RewriteEngine On enables mod_rewrite.
- RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} shows which URLs we do and don't want to run through the rewrite.

  1. In this case, we want to match example.com.
  2. ! means "not." We don't want to rewrite a URL that already includes folder1, because then it would keep getting folder1 added, and it would become an infinitely long URL.
- [NC] matches both upper- and lower-case versions of the URL.
- RewriteRule defines a particular rule.
- The first string of characters after RewriteRule defines what the original URL looks like. There's a more detailed explanation of the special characters at the end of this article.
- The second string after RewriteRule defines the new URL. This is in relation to the document root (html) directory. / means the html directory itself, and subfolders can also be specified.

For Reference [click here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Shivraj thanks for help, what i need if the user type http://www.localhost.com/category/computers/ in url it should show http://www.localhost.com/code_category/computers/ page content.

Comment: In that case `RewriteRule ^/category/computers/$ code_category/computers/`

Answer (score 1):

You only want to redirect `code_category` to `category`externally and keep the path as it is internally so, try this :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+category/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^code_category/(.*)$ category/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ code_category/$1 [L]
```

The above will redirect any request contains`code_category/whatever` to `category/whatever` externally and keep the internal path as it is .

If you want only request contains `code_category/computers/` change it to this :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+category/computers/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^code_category/computers/(.*)$ category/computers/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^category/computers/(.*)$ code_category/computers/$1 [L]
```

test it , if it is fine change `302` to `301` for permanent redirection.

**Note:**  clear your browser cache then test it.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, where shall i add it i have  mentioned my htaccess file above.

Comment: after  RewriteBase  /